# Sharing/Updating a JTable from multiple objects?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm working on a project for my concurrent programming class and have run into some trouble with JTable.  The project simulates a world full of ports, each port has people with skills at it to accomplish jobs (in threads). My goal is to have the GUI display the number of people with each skill are at each port at any given time and update as people become available/busy.

I create a JTable and a DefaultTableModel (with column names) in the GUI class, then pass the model to each port's constructor.  The ports then add a row to the model based on an array containing the port name and values for the number of workers based on skill.  As people change, I update the array and fire an event, caught in the GUI class (this does get caught) where I have tried to update the table by resetting the model, but to no avail.

GUI Class:

```
private DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(JOBS, 0);
private JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
...
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
    table.setModel(tableModel);
}
```

Port Class:

```
public SeaPort(Scanner scan, DefaultTableModel mod) { //mod is the tableModel
    super(scan);
    model = mod;
    updatePoolData();
    model.addRow(poolData);
}

private void updatePoolData(){
    poolData[0] = this.name;
    synchronized(availability){
        for(int i=1; i<16;i++){
            poolData[i] = availability[i][0];
        }
    }
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

The rows get added appropriately as the ports are created, and as I mentioned the TableModelEvent is coming through to the GUI every time that method is called, so I'm at a loss as to why the table cells remain at 0 (I checked the poolData array and it's updating as it should).  I've tried the suggestions in other posts (short of creating my own table model, but I don't think that would solve this since the events are firing) with no luck.

Note: I am not required to use a JTable to accomplish this I just wanted to try something new, so this isn't cheating and I may end up doing something else anyway.  I just want to know why this isn't working.

Comment: At a guess, your view is displaying one model, but your code is updating another.

Comment: For better help sooner post a [mcve].